# Testing if statements

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, if-statement, jestjs

I've got a few lines uncovered but I can't seem to get coverage. Tried all sorts of testing with no luck.

It's my 3 if statements below.

No idea who to fix this.

```
const user = getState('user');

if (user) {
    if (user.token) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${user.token}`;
    }

    if (user.account) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Account-Id'] = user.account.id;
    }
}
```

Comment: by just adding an `account` property to `user`?

Comment: is `getUser` imported as a module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have managed to resolve the issue after reading [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/155880/unit-testing-multiple-conditions-in-an-if-statement).

I basically had to add a separate unit test that was true and false for each of my if statements.